# Entity Framework 6 Mixed Stored Procedure and SQL Query Generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Reading the EF documentation on CodePlex I understand it's not currently possible to use both a [mixture of stored procedure and SQL query generation](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20First%20Insert%2FUpdate%2FDelete%20Stored%20Procedure%20Mapping) for persisting domain model changes.

However, there are numerous reasons why I find this frustrating that it doesn't allow me to use a mixture of both when its predecessor - Linq 2 SQL, allowed me to do this.

I have a complicated scenario for persisting my domain model to multiple tables in the database, whereby I want to use a stored procedure for insertion.  The reason why I don't want to use a stored procedure for updates is that there isn't a clean way to run the update on only those columns affected - parsing all values to the update sproc I would have to update all fields for that record (unless I select all old values again for comparison or include the fields in the UPDATE statement predicate clause - kind of messy both ways).  This is a problem due to triggers being attached to the table in which individual fields are checked for updates, this is more of a legacy system issue - so we won't go down the road of the subjective matter of using triggers being a good design.

Passing all fields to the update sproc even if they haven't changed is unnecessary and can contribute to network traffic, whereas EF knows which fields to explicitly update when using SQL query generation mode.

Are there any entity framework add-ons which allow me to use a mixture of stored procedure mapping for inserts, and then SQL query generation for updates for model persistency?

For my database I am specifically using SQL Server, however I believe a suitable add-on wouldn't be coupled to my chosen data store.

Comment: could not understand what you are trying to achieve ... are you saying you want to update the entity but not all columns ?

Comment: I want to persist the changes of the entity but for only the fields which have changed.  If I use EF query generation then EF will create an UPDATE statement for only those fields which have changed (desired), if I use SPROC mapping then EF will pass all fields of the entity to the SPROC - but how do I know which ones have changed in my SPROC so that I run an UPDATE stmt ONLY on those ones which have changed - this is important because in SQL Server if you UPDATE a column with the SAME value then the underlying triggers still get executed - we have legacy logic around column names in triggers

Comment: Simply, I want to use a SPROC for entity INSERTS, but EF query generation for UPDATES (so only those fields which have changed get updated).  EF 6 doesn't allow me todo this mixed mode, therefore is there a suitable solution out there (possibly an add-on) which does?  I want this all achieved using `SaveChanges` so the EF still handles all of the persistence.

Answer (score 0):

you can call a stored procedure (if it is already in the database), or you can write query and execute it.

I'm not currently on the laptop with a visual studio but is should work like this:

```
  List<Ekipa> result = new List<Ekipa>();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (UsersContext uc = new UsersContext())
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(uc.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();

                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("procedurename", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 12);
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }

        result = (from myRow in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  select new Ekipa()
                  {
                      UserId = myRow.Field<int>("UserId"),
                      UserName = myRow.Field<string>("UserName"),
                      Bodovi = myRow.Field<int>("Bod"),
                      OU = myRow.Field<int>("OU"),
                      Gol = myRow.Field<int>("PostignutiGolovi"),
                  }).ToList();
```

just enable multiple MultipleActiveResultSets in your config

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=**.**.***.***;Initial Catalog=**;User ID=**_DBUser; Password=***; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: I understand that I can explicitly call the SQL myself but this isn't a scalable solution for all models tracked by my database context.  I simply want to have the ability of EF to figure this out using `SaveChanges` where I can explicitly define this in my CodeFirst mappings.  The problem is I can only have all CUD operations mapped to stored procedures OR all dynamically generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for that mixture too. 
`DbSet` has a method called `SqlQuery` where you can place your custom `SELECT` queries (with some warnings). You can call Store Procedures too.
Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx where this exmaple is shown:

```
using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("dbo.GetBlogs").ToList(); 
}
```

I just used it for myself in this way:

```
db.RegistroSet.SqlQuery("DELETE FROM RegistroSET; SELECT * FROM RegistroSet").ToList();
int c = db.RegistroSet.Count();
```

...because I actually wanted to clear my 200.000 rows table. It was fast and the context is ok. But I had to include the `Select` for manteining context's integrity. The call for `ToList()` is important even if I don't get the result.